# Recursively list directories

Tags: beginner, c, posix

How does the following look to list the directories on a posix system? This is actually the first piece of C code that I've written where I've actually been able to use for a real-world problem!

````
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define handle_error(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct linux_dirent {
    unsigned long  d_ino;
    off_t          d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char           d_name[];
};

void print_files(char* dir, FILE* out)
{
    // open the file
    int fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
    if (fd == -1) handle_error("Error opening file.\n");

    // grab a buffer to read the file data
    #define BUF_SIZE (1024*1024*1)
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * BUF_SIZE);
    if (buffer == NULL) handle_error("Error malloc.\n");

    // do the getdents syscall writing to buffer
    int num_read = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    if (num_read == -1) handle_error("Error getdents syscall.\n");
    close(fd);

    for (long buffer_position = 0; buffer_position < num_read;) {

        struct linux_dirent *d = (struct linux_dirent *) (buffer + buffer_position);
        char d_type = *(buffer + buffer_position + d->d_reclen - 1);

        // skip on . and .. in the listing
        if (d->d_name[0] == '.') {
            buffer_position += d->d_reclen;
            continue;
        }

        // path = dir + '/' + name
        char path[400];
        strcpy(path, dir);
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path, d->d_name);

        // recursive call, as necessary
        if (d_type == DT_DIR)
             print_files(path, out);
        else if (d_type == DT_REG)
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", path);

        // advance buffer position
        buffer_position += d->d_reclen;

    }

    free(buffer);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char dir[1024];
    strcpy(dir, argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".");
    FILE *out = fopen("c-log.txt", "w");
    fprintf(out, "-------------[ START ]---------------------\n");
    print_files(dir, out);
}
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> #define handle_error(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)
> ```

There's a long-standing convention to use `UPPER_CASE` for preprocessor macros.  This helps draw attention to them as *text replacements*, which don't obey the same rules of scope as C identifiers (and which sometimes - though not in this case - expand their arguments multiple times).

> ```
> void print_files(char* dir, FILE* out)
> ```

Why a `const char* dir`?  Surely we have no need to overwrite its contents?  Also, I'd be inclined to always write to `stdout` in this program - let the user apply ordinary shell plumbing if a different destination is desired.  That's easier than having a special argument in each program.

In larger programs, it's usually a bad idea to `exit()` from within functions, particularly if it's possible to either recover, or produce useful information regardless of the error.  As a concrete example, if we find a subdirectory we can't read, it's probably more helpful to emit a warning message to `stderr` but continue listing the directories the user does have permissions for.

The code using `open()` and `syscall()` is much lower level than we'd normally use for this, and tightly bound to Linux rather than POSIX as claimed.  I think `opendir()` and `readdir()` would be more suited.

Be careful with resource management and non-local exits in C.  We only reach `close(fd)` in the success case.  Although `handle_error()` currently exits the program, if we change that in future, we'll find ourselves leaking file descriptors.  Kudos for closing the descriptor before the recursive call - it's easy to leave it open until the end of the function, and you avoided that trap.

> ```
> char* buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * BUF_SIZE);
> ```

The multiplication by `sizeof *buffer` is borderline pointless.  I say "borderline" in case there's a chance that we might want to change the type (but still have `BUF_SIZE` of them).

We don't seem to handle reading directories larger than `BUF_SIZE` at all - not even with an error message.

> ```
>     char path[400];
>     strcpy(path, dir);
>     strcat(path, "/");
>     strcat(path, d->d_name);
> ```

Where's that `400` come from?  Why not use the system's `MAX_PATH` constant?

`strcpy()` followed by `strcat()` is wasteful - that causes another traversal of the string just written, in order to find where to start writing.  In this case, we could use `printf()` like this:

```
int path_len = snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s/%s", dir, d->d_name);
```

Remember to test `path_len` to determine whether the path was truncated at this stage.

> ```
>     if (d_type == DT_DIR)
>          print_files(path, out);
>     else if (d_type == DT_REG)
>         fprintf(out, "%s\n", path);
> ```

Why don't we print the other kinds of file?  I wouldn't expect all my symlinks, sockets, FIFOs and device files to simply disappear from the listing unless I specifically asked for that.

> ```
>    fprintf(out, "-------------[ START ]---------------------\n");
> ```

Consider using `fputs()` when there's no conversions to be done.

As a general style point, I'd advise more vertical space for conditionals, and use of braces as a consistent rule.  E.g.

```
if (buffer == NULL) {
    handle_error("Error malloc.\n");
}
```

Comment: While sizeof is redundant when the type is `char`, I think it's a reasonable habit to get into always writing `type *var = malloc(sizeof *var * count);`. And little clarity is lost in using `printf()` with no conversions (the compiler will almost certainly optimize it, so no performance is lost either).

Comment: Yes, to both of those points.

Comment: " use UPPER_CASE for preprocessor macros." is interesting in that it was followed shortly by  `FILE`, a type that may or may not be defined via a macro.

Comment: "Consider using fputs() when there's no conversions to be done." --> is OK, but borders on premature optimization.  Good compilers emit efficient code with `fprintf(out, "[ START ]\n");` or `fputs( "[ START ]\n", out);`.  For such minor issues, best to follow groups coding standard and/or clarity.